# "AND OR" Usage in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

what is different (in performance ) when using :
A:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, col7 
  FROM xTable  
 WHERE (col1 > 0) 
   AND (col7 >= 0) 
    OR (col2 > 0)
   AND (col7 >= 0) 
    OR (col3 > 0) 
   AND (col7 >= 0)
```

B:and using:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, col7
  FROM xTable
 WHERE ( (col1 > 0) OR (col2 > 0) OR (col3 > 0) )
   AND (col7 >= 0)
```

Comment: did you try running them or looking at the execution plans?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it yourself? Are you dealing with a large/busy enough system that such a microscopic change would make major differences in your budget?

Comment: Choose the one you can read and understand easily. Unless you are dealing with millions of rows, the performance tuning you are expecting to get from this will not exist.

Comment: you need brackets in the first query to make it equivalent to the second

Comment: @Bohemian - I don't think so. `AND` has higher precedence than or. I'd tend to think that the second one might be more likely to do a range scan on `col7` if a suitable index exists.

Comment: I would personally go with option B since I find it more readable, but I would reorder it so that the col7 comparison comes first. Not that it would make a huge performance difference unless you had millions of rows, but you at least can bail once that compare fails as opposed to having to perform possibly 3 comparisons only to find that the last one fails.

Comment: @pstrjds the query optimizer can rearrange the conditions how it pleases so changing the order will not effect performance.

Comment: Improper use of brackets - you don't need them around *every* single WHERE clause

Comment: Logically no different, but I found that every time the execution plan results different execution time!

Comment: How much do execution times vary?  Are you expecting the same execution time for a query every time you run it?

Comment: @Magnus - I was basing that off of the suggestions from the SQL cheat sheet - (http://dotnet4all.com/factsheet-for-sql-server-developers.html) which recommends putting the least likely true AND expression first. Now thinking about it, "least likely" and short circuit evaluation from a C#/C++ standpoint are two different animals - thanks for pointing out the optimizer thing.

Answer (score 0):

They will, for all intents and purposes, be identical in performance. To get that extra nanosecond, try putting the (col7 >= 0) clause first in B. In any case, the optimiser may rewrite/refactor the query so they have identical performance.

When people are really trying to do this kind of thing quickly, they use a bitmap index, except SQL Server doesn't do those as I recall.

An equivalent approach is to generate a "bit" column, and index on that column, but that is a little off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Trying against this table

```
CREATE TABLE xTable
(
col7 INT PRIMARY KEY,
Col1 INT,
Col2 INT,
Col3 INT
)
```

Both versions of the query give identical execution plans with a range seek on `col7 >= Scalar Operator((0))` and a residual predicate `[Col1]>(0) OR [Col2]>(0) OR [Col3]>(0)` so at least in that test it makes no performance difference at all.